# How to run two projects simultaneously in C# XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xna, kinect

I have two created two projects.

1. Virtual Dressing Room
2. Kinect for Mouse

Both projects are stored in different project files. Kinect can only support 1 project at a time. So i can't run both projects at a single time. I want to combine both of these projects, so that when i run this `dressing room`  project `Kinect for Mouse`  start with it.
Kindly tell me  that is there any way in Visual studio to combine 2 projects so that both projects can Run at a single time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your solution => properties => startup project.

Then check "Multiple startup projects" and select projects you want to start.